# Are there really 330 million gods we worship? Where can we find a reference to this?

Tags: scripture

We as Hindus are encouraged to worship our own Ista devata but are told that there are over 330 million Gods whose blessing we seek during auspicious like weddings, etc. Where do we get this number from? Is this derived from Vedas or other scripts? Is there a list of names for all the 330 million devatas?